# Building a graph from a list or dict - Python

Tags: python

I have an example list of word lists like this:

```
[['rowerowy', 'rower']
['rowerzysta', 'rower']
['domeczek',  'domek']
['domek', 'dom']
['rowerzystka', 'rowerzysta']]
```

and I need to concatenate words into dependency groups, we are making a graph of connections between the forms:

```
rowerowy --> rower <-- rowerzysta <--- rowerzystka

domeczek --> domek --> dom
```

If they are not attached to any pairs in the relation, they form a graph with one edge.

Any ideas ?

I am making a dictionary

```
data = [['rowerowy', 'rower'],
['rowerzysta', 'rower'],
['domeczek',  'domek'],
['domek', 'dom'],
['rowerzystka', 'rowerzysta']]


dc={}

for a in data:
    if a[1] in dc:
        dc[a[1]].append(a[0])
    else:
        dc[a[1]] = [a[0]]
```

out:

```
{'rower': ['rowerowy', 'rowerzysta'],
'domek': ['domeczek'], 
'dom': ['domek'],
'rowerzysta': ['rowerzystka']}
```

or:

```
def maketree(source):
    graph={}
    for pair in source:
        nodein,nodeout=pair
        if nodeout in graph:
            graph[nodeout].add(nodein)
        else:
            graph[nodeout]={nodein}
    graph[None]=set(graph.keys()).difference(set.union(*graph.values()))
    return graph
```

The second approach is better because I delete duplicate words in the dictionary values.

How to write it out graphically?

Comment: Please provide valid input data. Also, what if more than two words are pointing to the same one? Your representation on one line can't be used. Finally, have you tried anything to solve this? As shown here, it looks like you just want us to write the code for you...

Comment: If there are more of the same words in the dictionary, we omit them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the [networkx](https://networkx.org/) library:

```
import networkx as nx

data = [['rowerowy', 'rower'],
['rowerzysta', 'rower'],
['domeczek',  'domek'],
['domek', 'dom'],
['rowerzystka', 'rowerzysta']]


#instantiate graph
G = nx.Graph()

# add word connections as edges
G.add_edges_from(data)

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]